# Json query on button press python / django

Tags: python, json, django

Currently as it stands I have a search bar and a button on my homepage like so.

```
<div class="input-group">
<input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder="City or Zipcode" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addressSearch">Search</button>
</span>
</div>
```

I have created a api.py file which is within my websites folder which looks like so.

```
import urllib2
import json

locu_api = '****'

def loc_search(query):
api_key = locu_api
url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=' + api_key
locality = query.replace(' ', '%20')
final_url = url + "&locality=" + locality + "&category=restaurant"
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
data = json.load(json_obj)

for item in data['objects']:
    print item['name']
    print item['phone']
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is when the user search's for a city e.g. New York then the loc_search(query) is called populating the search field '(query)' with the users input and the data then being displayed.

I haven't much experience with either django or api's so any help would be invaluable. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your html should put in a `form` with a 'action':

```
<form action="{% url "search" %}">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input name="query" id="address" type="textbox" placeholder="City or Zipcode" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addressSearch">Search</button>
    </span>
</div>
</form>
```

Then you need a `urls.py` file contains:

```
url(r"^api/", 'loc_search', name="search")
```

And in views you can do like this:

```
import urllib2
import json

locu_api = '****'

def loc_search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    api_key = locu_api
    url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=' + api_key
    locality = query.replace(' ', '%20')
    final_url = url + "&locality=" + locality + "&category=restaurant"
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
    data = json.load(json_obj)

    for item in data['objects']:
        print item['name']
        print item['phone']
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time so in my url's 
    url(r"^api/", 'loc_search(query)', name="search"),
like that?

Comment: `url(r"^api/", 'loc_search', name="search")` with no parameter, the `request` will be pass into loc_search automatically by django

Comment: so do i just pass search into the form action or loc_search? sorry just a little confused

Comment: The `action` is the url to your `loc_search`, and you can get the search parameter in `loc_search` like this: `value = request.GET.get("key")`. And then you can deal with it.

Comment: Sorry but that's just confused me even more, so do I call the url before similarly like {% url "search" as loc_search %}, and then my search parameters within my api.py would be request.GET.get("key")